# Control vmware workstation network "bandwidth" settings from command line

Tags: networking, command-line, vmware-workstation

Is there a way I can use the command line to adjust the network bandwidth settings of a running VMware Workstation instance?

Comment: Check out this server fault post. Relatively matches your requirement. http://serverfault.com/questions/39116/limit-vmware-virtual-ethernet-bandwidth

Comment: Unfortunately it seems changes to the vmx file aren't picked up by already running vms, so this doesn't really answer my question. I need to throttle the vm's usage in response to changing conditions, dynamically.